# Global use of values obtained in draw let

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In one of my `tikzpicture`s, I found an angle I labelled `\n2`.  I would like to use this value to rotate a node.  However, when I try, in the node options, `rotate = \n2`, I am told undefined control sequence.  My guess is `\n2` is only accessible in the `\draw let` command.

Can I set `\n2` to be used globally?

---

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw (O) -- +(3, 0) coordinate (P1);
  \draw[name path = sline] (O) -- (3, 2) coordinate (P2);

  \draw[-stealth] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (P1),
    \p2 = (P2),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {1cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2)/2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3,
  start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2] node[right, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3)
  {$\theta$} \pgfextra{\xdef\myn{\n2}} ;

  \path[name path = line1] (1.5, 0) -- +(0, 1.25);
  \path[name path = line2] (2, 0) -- +(0, 1.5);
  \path[name intersections = {of = sline and line1, by = P3}];
  \path[name intersections = {of = sline and line2, by = P4}];

  \draw (P3) -- ($(P3)!.25cm!-90:(O)$) coordinate (P5);
  \draw (P4) -- ($(P4)!.25cm!-90:(O)$) coordinate (P6);
  \draw (P5) -- (P6) node[pos = .5, below, font = \tiny, rotate = {\n2}] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

No matter where I place `\pgfextra{\xdef\myn{\n2}}` after in, I get undefined control sequence

Comment: after `in` write `\pgfextra{\xdef\myn{\n1}}` somewhere suitable, preferably at the very end.

Comment: My mistake. I changed it to `xdef`

Comment: After you define `\myn` you need to use `\myn` instead of `\n2`

Comment: @percusse ok thanks.  Do you want to make this an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To do auxillary computations, you can make use of `\pgfextra{}`. Then you can define a global variable using expanded global definition.

```
\documentclass[tikz, convert = false]{standalone}%

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);

  \draw (O) -- +(3, 0) coordinate (P1);
  \draw[name path = sline] (O) -- (3, 2) coordinate (P2);

  \draw[-stealth] let
    \p0 = (O),
    \p1 = (P1),
    \p2 = (P2),
    \n1 = {atan2(\y1 - \y0, \x1 - \x0)},
    \n2 = {atan2(\y2 - \y0, \x2 - \x0)},
    \n3 = {1cm},
    \n4 = {(\n1 + \n2)/2}
  in (O) +(\n1:\n3) arc[radius = \n3,
  start angle = \n1, end angle = \n2] node[right, font = \tiny] at (\n4:\n3)
  {$\theta$} \pgfextra{\xdef\myn{\n2}} ;

  \path[name path = line1] (1.5, 0) -- +(0, 1.25);
  \path[name path = line2] (2, 0) -- +(0, 1.5);
  \path[name intersections = {of = sline and line1, by = P3}];
  \path[name intersections = {of = sline and line2, by = P4}];

  \draw (P3) -- ($(P3)!.25cm!-90:(O)$) coordinate (P5);
  \draw (P4) -- ($(P4)!.25cm!-90:(O)$) coordinate (P6);
  \draw (P5) -- (P6) node[pos = .5, below, font = \tiny, rotate = {\myn}] {$M$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]